# Is it possible to dismiss keyboard in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using QLPreviewController as child view in my application, and want to dismiss keybord that is shown when I open password protected files. I was trying to change first responder and send -endEditing message, but nothing helps.
Did anyone try to do something simillar?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since QLPreviewController runs in **XPC(sand-boxing)**, I'm afraid you cannot do this and neither do gesture or any other recognizers work.

Comment: I was able to do it by changing windows layer. Moved keyboard on the front of app really helps